# Delete duplicates in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database that looks like this:

```
upID | bsID | pID | upUren | upDatum
-----+------+-----+--------+----------
1    | 4    | 2   | 12     | 2011-01-26 00:00:00
2      4      2   | 12     | 2011-01-26 00:00:00
3      4      2   | 12     | 2011-01-27 00:00:00
4      4      2   | 12     | 2011-01-28 00:00:00
```

I want to delete every row where `pID` is equal AND `bsID` is equal AND `upDatum` is equal. So far i've got this:

`DELETE FROM twh_uren_prognose WHERE EXISTS (SELECT b.* FROM twh_uren_prognose b WHERE twh_uren_prognose.upDatum = b.upDatum and twh_uren_prognose.upID <> b.upID`

But this gives me this error:

An exception occurred while executing

```
   DELETE FROM twh_uren_prognose 
   WHERE EXISTS 
             (
               SELECT b.* FROM twh_uren_prognose b 
               WHERE twh_uren_prognose.upDatum = b.upDatum 
               and twh_uren_prognose.upID <> b.upID
              )
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table
>   'twh_uren_prognose' for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: You want delete all the rows with same bsID , pID,upDatum are equal or just remove te duplciatedc rows and leave a single row?

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes i want to delete all the rows with same bsID, pID, and upDatum and leave one row of the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you " want to delete all the rows with same bsID, pID, and upDatum and leave one row of the duplicates."

you could use a NOT in select for the min  upId group by the column you want compare

```
delete from twh_uren_prognose 
where  updId NOT IN ( select t.my_id from (
    select min(upID ) my_id
    from twh_uren_prognose 
    group by bsID, pID , upDatum ) t
)
```

Comment: This is exactly the same query as @rakwaht posted. Gives me the same error as that: An exception occurred while executing 'delete from twh_uren_prognose where upID NOT IN ( select min(upID ) from twh_uren_prognose group by bsID, pID , upDatum ) ': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'twh_uren_prognose' for update in FROM clause

Comment: answer  updated .. adding the creation a temporary table based  on subselect .. let me know

Comment: It's not a temporay table but an alias.

Comment: @DanielE.  correct but this reference  force the dbengine to buil a temporary table ..(is not a pure mapping between column or table name as are normally the alias  )  and is for this "copied values " that is possible delete the rows of the "same" table  ..

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a `GROUP BY` query:

```
DELETE FROM twh_uren_prognose WHERE upID NOT IN (
   SELECT temp.myID(
      SELECT MIN(upID) AS myID FROM twh_uren_prognose GROUP BY pID, bsID, upDatum);
   ) AS temp
)
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843719/5226835) answer this query could solve your problem

delete from twh_uren_prognose 
where  updId NOT IN ( select t.my_id from (
    select min(upID ) my_id
    from twh_uren_prognose 
    group by bsID, pID , upDatum ) t
)

Comment: This query gives me the same error: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM twh_uren_prognose WHERE upID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(upID) FROM twh_uren_prognose GROUP BY pID, bsID, upDatum)': SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'twh_uren_prognose' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You are near  ..  you should add  an alias .MIN(upID) upID. in your subselect otherwise the outer select cant select upID  ..  do  it so  i can upvote

Comment: @scaisEdge is this correct? Unfortunately I cannot run it on anything so this may contains syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify wich table you are deleting on and it's better to use a left join like this :

```
 DELETE t1
 FROM twh_uren_prognose t1
 LEFT JOIN 
    twh_uren_prognose t2 ON t1.upDatum = t2.upDatum 
 WHERE t1.upID <> t2.upID
```

If you want to keep 1 row, let's say the min Id here is what you should do :

```
 DELETE t1
 FROM twh_uren_prognose t1
 LEFT JOIN 
    twh_uren_prognose t2 ON t1.upDatum = t2.upDatum 
 WHERE t1.upID > t2.upID AND t1.column1 = t2.column1 etc...
```

Comment: This does indeed remove duplicates, is my version of this answer also viable? ---> DELETE t1
 FROM twh_uren_prognose t1
 LEFT JOIN 
    twh_uren_prognose t2 ON t1.upDatum = t2.upDatum 
 WHERE t1.upID <> t2.upID AND t1.bsID = t2.bsID AND t1.pID = t2.pID

Comment: I have edited, if you want to keep 1 row. I really think my answer is better than scaisEdge's for performance reasons.

Comment: If i run your second query it deletes all the rows, it doesn't leave one row. I don't really care much about performance.

Comment: It shouldn't in my second query what did you write exactly ?

Comment: My bad, i did the comparisation wrong: You said: WHERE t1.upID > t2.upID. I did: WHERE t1.upID <> t2.upID. This also works. You're right

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one,

```
DELETE FROM twh_uren_prognose 
WHERE pID = bsID AND pID =upDatum;
```

This will do your work. There is no need for the complex query

Comment: How is this going to work? My upDatum field is a DATETIME as you have already seen i think. The fact that both of those are called ID's suggests that they are INTEGERS. So this comparisation is never working. Sorry